# Equation with logarithms with different bases.

Tags: logarithms

> Solve the equation $$\log_x(2)\cdot \log_{2x}(2)=\log_{4x}(2)$$ for $x$.

I am not able to work out what I need to do. Can we find the answer using quadratic formula?

Comment: Hint: start by base change formula and switch all you $\log$ in base $2$. E.g. $\log_x2=\frac{\log_2 2}{\log_2 x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\log_{x}{2}\cdot\log_{2x}{2}=\log_{4x}{2}$

$\frac{\log_{n}{2}}{\log_{n}{x}}\cdot\frac{\log_{n}{2}}{\log_{n}{2}+\log_{n}{x}}=\frac{\log_{n}{2}}{2\log_{n}{2}+\log_{n}{x}}$

$(\log_{n}{x})^{2}=2(\log_{n}{2})^{2}$

$\log_{n}{x}=\pm\sqrt{2}\log_{n}{2}$

$x=2^{\pm\sqrt{2}}$